# Javascript:: Image previews

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, image, input

I want to preview 4 pictures before I upload them to my laravel app. 
I can see the first preview image when I upload the first picture.

But if I upload a second picture, the first preview image changes to the second picture. But I cannot see the second picture preview in the second preview field.

The same thing happens to the third and the fourth picture. Only the first preview field changes.

> How can I show 4 image previews?

html

```
<div class="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
            @if(isset($post))
            <img src="" id="image-preview__image">
            @else
            <img src="../../blog-image/S__3530766.jpg" id="preview">
            @endif
        </div>

        <input type="text" class="name" value="NAME">

        <textarea name="profile" cols="20" rows="5" class="profile" value="profile">profile</textarea>



        <div class="preview">
                    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="profile_img">
            <label for="file" >
                Add profile photo
            </label>
        </div>

<div class="content-image-preview" id="imagePreview">
            @if(isset($post))
            <img src="" id="image-preview__image">
            @else
            <img src="../../LPImages/jezael-melgoza-alY6_OpdwRQ-unsplash.jpg" id="preview2">
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="preview" id="add">
                <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
            <label for="file">
                Add photo
            </label>
        </div>
<input type="text" value="TITLE" class="section-title">

    <div class="content-image-preview" id="imagePreview">
        @if(isset($post))
        <img src="" id="image-preview__image">
        @else
        <img src="../../LPImages/jezael-melgoza-alY6_OpdwRQ-unsplash.jpg" id="preview3">
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="preview" id="add">
                <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
        <label for="file">
            Add photo
        </label>
    </div>
 <div class="content-image-preview" id="imagePreview">
        @if(isset($post))
        <img src="" id="image-preview__image">
        @else
        <img src="../../LPImages/jezael-melgoza-alY6_OpdwRQ-unsplash.jpg" id="preview4">
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="preview" id="add">
                <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
        <label for="file">
            Add photo
        </label>
    </div>
```

javascript

```
const input = document.getElementById("file");
const previewImage = document.getElementById("image-preview__image");

input.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    const file = this.files[0];
    if (previewImage != null && previewImage.length < 1){


    for (var i=0; i<previewImage.length; i+=1){
        if(file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.addEventListener("load", function(){
                previewImage.setAttribute("src", this.result);
            });

            previewImage.style.display = "block";

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            previewImage.setAttribute("src", "");
        }
    }
   }
  }
);
```

Comment: I think you need to feel free to ask the question

Comment: you have multiple `img` elements with the same id `image-preview__image` ~ that will not work

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say, "if my question is unclear, feel free to ask an additional explanation."

Comment: I think the point @YotamDahan was making was that you haven't actually asked a question

Comment: @RamRaider ok !

Comment: Rather than using a duplicate ID, use another attribute to help identify the relevant preview element and then use parent/sibling selectors to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the correct preview element you need a reliable way to query elements further up the DOM in this case - and because the HTML is not constant I modified your original slightly so that various distinct parts were separated using `section` tags - thus allowing a simple DOM traversal to find the correct preview `img` tag. In the following you'll note that I have omitted the template tags you were using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Image previews</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>

            <!--
                slightly modified and without templating tags, otherwise essentially the same. ID attributes replaced with class attributes
            -->

            <section>
                <div class="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
                    <img class="image-preview__image">
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="name" value="NAME">
                <textarea name="profile" cols="20" rows="5" class="profile" value="profile">profile</textarea>
                <div class="preview">
                    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="profile_img">
                    <label for="file" >Add profile photo</label>
                </div>
            </section>



            <section>
                <div class="content-image-preview" id="imagePreview">
                    <img class="image-preview__image">
                </div>
                <div class="preview" id="add">
                    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
                    <label for="file">Add photo</label>
                </div>
            </section>



            <section>
                <input type="text" value="TITLE" class="section-title">
                <div class="content-image-preview" id="imagePreview">
                    <img class="image-preview__image">
                </div>
                <div class="preview" id="add">
                    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
                    <label for="file">Add photo</label>
                </div>
            </section>



            <section>
                <div class="content-image-preview" id="imagePreview">
                    <img class="image-preview__image">
                </div>
                <div class="preview" id="add">
                    <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
                    <label for="file">Add photo </label>
                </div>
            </section>


        </form>


        <script>
            const findsection=function(n){
                while(n && n.tagName.toLowerCase()!='section')n=n.parentNode;
                return n;
            };

            Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]') ).forEach( input=>{
                input.addEventListener('change',function(e){
                    let section=findsection( e.target );
                    let file=this.files[0];
                    let reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
                            let img=section.querySelector( 'img.image-preview__image' );
                                img.src=this.result;
                                img.width=200;
                        });
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                })
            })
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

```js
const findsection=function(n){
 while(n && n.tagName.toLowerCase()!='section')n=n.parentNode;
 return n;
};

Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]') ).forEach( input=>{
 input.addEventListener('change',function(e){
  let section=findsection( e.target );
  let file=this.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
   reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
    let img=section.querySelector( 'img.image-preview__image' );
     img.src=this.result;
     img.width=200;
   });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 })
})
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="image-preview" id="imagePreview">
  <img class="image-preview__image">
 </div>
 <input type="text" class="name" value="NAME">
 <textarea name="profile" cols="20" rows="5" class="profile" value="profile">profile</textarea>
 <div class="preview">
  <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="profile_img">
  <label for="file" >Add profile photo</label>
 </div>
</section>
<section>
 <div class="content-image-preview" id="imagePreview">
  <img class="image-preview__image">
 </div>
 <div class="preview" id="add">
  <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
  <label for="file">Add photo</label>
 </div>
</section>
<section>
 <input type="text" value="TITLE" class="section-title">
 <div class="content-image-preview" id="imagePreview">
  <img class="image-preview__image">
 </div>
 <div class="preview" id="add">
  <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
  <label for="file">Add photo</label>
 </div>
</section>
<section>
 <div class="content-image-preview" id="imagePreview">
  <img class="image-preview__image">
 </div>
 <div class="preview" id="add">
  <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
  <label for="file">Add photo </label>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried but I had an error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null.

Comment: can you confirm that you altered the duplicate ID attributes by converting to a `class` attribute instead?

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple **IMG** elements with the same id **image-preview__image**.
User different ID for each element then it will work.

```
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">
```

further name can not be same in multiple places.

Comment: I renamed each id name to image-preview__image, image-preview__image1 image-preview__image2, and image-preview__image3 also, I changed valuables in my javascript code, but it didn't work.

Comment: <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="image">

Comment: name ="image" can not be same in multiple places.